# can't run a pull queue handler inside a custom vm

Tags: python, google-app-engine, docker

I have deployed the hello world example of the `app.yaml`, `worker.yaml`and the `queue.yaml`

```
runtime: python27
```

Since My worker is more complicated, I need to install third party `pips` and other specific dependencies like `openCV` - so I need to run this handler from within a custom vm meaning `Dockerfile`.

I want to start simple, running what worked before , The "hello world" in a simple python container. 
so I've modified the `worker.yaml`

```
service: worker
api_version: 1
#runtime: vm # python27
runtime: custom
vm: true # python27
instance_class: B1
threadsafe: yes
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
network:
  instance_tag: ssh
  name: olympus-dev
env_variables:
  PYTHON_ENV: lab

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.APP

#libraries:
#- name: jinja2
#  version: latest
#
```

and the `app.yaml`

```
runtime: custom
vm: true # python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
network:
  instance_tag: ssh
  name: olympus-dev
env_variables:
  PYTHON_ENV: lab

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.APP

#libraries:
#- name: jinja2
#  version: latest
#
```

and the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python

# Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
# system-level packages.
RUN virtualenv /env

# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
#ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
#RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app

# Run a WSGI server to serve the application. gunicorn must be declared as
# a dependency in requirements.txt.
CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

Comment: is there a specific question you're trying to answer? any errors you saw?

Comment: yeah, sorry if I wasn't clear. trying to make the pull queue handler work inside the container.

Comment: ok, what did you try and importantly, did you get any error messages or logs that might have clues? always include as much about your problem when asking questions--reduces the need for more questions from us. include any assumptions you've made as well, as those can be wrong. HTH